# A ffmpeg h.265 hardware issue

Tags: ffmpeg, converters, codec, h.265

Hi i have a ffmpeg hardware related problem. 
Simply put: The conversion works on mac, but on some TV screens the converted h.265 video will give a few seconds of delay when it starts playing!

A response will be much appreciated!

**Input:**

UHD(3840x2160) Prores 422(HQ) master file

What we used to recompile to a 16bit renderer:

```
brew uninstall ffmpeg
brew uninstall x265
brew uninstall --force x265
brew install x265 --16-bit
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-libass --with-libquvi --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opus --with-x265
```

**Code we used in FFMpeg:**

```
-b:v 36000k -maxrate 38000k -c:v libx265 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -x265-params "profile=main10:level=5.1:b=36000k" -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 256k
```

**Preferred Output**

```
3840x2160 resolution
10bit 4:2:0  colordepth
Main 10@L5.1@High format profile
MP4 container
HEVC codec
24p framerate
38Mb Variable bitrate
256Kb Variable bitrate/AAC audio
```

Output device is Tarakan UHD Stream Generator T7

**Our problem:**

The encode file that FFmpeg gives is correct, on spec level. 
I would like the file to have a Main 10 High level 5.1 format profile.
Based on the specs I've put into FFmpeg, it automatically makes a file with a level 5.0 profile, as it doesn't need a higher level based on the specs.

The file plays correctly on a Mac.
The file must also play correctly on a Tarakan UHD Stream Generator(media player with multiple HDMI outputs). The file takes a while to load, chops off 5-6 seconds of the beginning of the film, then plays correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this might be an decoder performance issue.

First, the bitrate. 38Mbps, is very high so the decoding takes more time for the first several frames.

Second, 10 bit also increases the loading of the decoder.

You may add "-t fast-decode" to x265 for better decoding performance.